# Halving a number loses fractional part

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, division

I want to show the halved value of a number on a `UILabel`. To do so, I tried getting the number using a `UITextField`, formatted the number from a `NSString` to a `NSNumber` and then divided by 2.

After that I wanted to show it on the `UILabel` but it doesn't show anything after the comma (decimal mark). Any idea how to solve this? I just need two digits after the comma.

This is my current `UIButton` code:

```
// first get the input
NSString *inputValue = self.numberInput.text;
NSLog(@"given number: %@", inputValue);

// divide the input by 2 & get the output
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSNumber *myNumber = [formatter numberFromString:inputValue];
NSNumber *toDivide = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2];

NSNumber *dividedNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[myNumber floatValue] / [toDivide floatValue]];
NSLog(@"divided value: %@", dividedNumber);

// print it out on the firstBill Label
self.firstBill.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[dividedNumber floatValue]];
```

Example Output:

```
2015-08-18 20:03:02.021 Week one[1364:37640] given number: 123.54
2015-08-18 20:03:02.022 Week one[1364:37640] divided value: 61
```

and I need something like

```
2015-08-18 20:03:02.021 Week one[1364:37640] given number: 123.54
2015-08-18 20:03:02.022 Week one[1364:37640] divided value: 61.77
```

Comment: Update your question with the log output. Give a specific example of what you actually get versus what you really want.

Comment: You're trying to store a fractional result in an integral type: `[NSNumber number**WithInt**:[myNumber floatValue] / [toDivide floatValue]]`

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't notice! Now it works!! Great thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that your code is going to fail in some user locales. Instead of using `stringWithFormat:` in the last line, use your number formatter to format the number back into a string. This will ensure that the number is formatted properly for the user's locale.

Comment: Surprisingly couldn't find a good duplicate of this, so I answered. There must be a reasonable one out there, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `numberWithInt:` to store the result of the division; this discards any fractional part.

You would do better to use `NSNumber` boxing:

```
@([myNumber floatValue] / [toDivide floatValue])
```

The compiler knows the type of the expression and will use the correct `NSNumber` constructor for you.